# Paperclip: Permission denied error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, imagemagick, paperclip

Paperclip works fine on localhost, but on my deployed app, it returns the following error when I try to update an avatar:

```
Errno::EACCES in UsersController#update
Permission denied - /rails_apps/website/releases/20150807211111/public/system/users/avatars/000/000/562
```

This is the line in my Users Controller that is getting singled out:

```
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
```

This is in my User Model:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :full => "400x720" }, :processors => [:cropper]
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

My server uses Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS.

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with file permissions and not with Ruby on Rails. Try to run the following command in a Terminal logged in with the user that runs the web server:

```
chmod -R +w /rails_apps/website/releases/20150807211111/public
```

Comment: Do you know what the difference is between this answer and the answer that says ’chmod 777 /rails_apps...'?

Comment: The `+w` means add write permissions and will give write permission to the user and group, it's equivalent to 775. With 777 you will give write permissions to all users in the machine, which is quite dangerous for the security.

Comment: @JoeMorano Here you have a nice tutorial about that: http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/permissions.php

Comment: I tried `chmod -R +w`, `chmod 755`, and `chmod 777`, but each time I kept getting the exact same error.

Comment: @JoeMorano You can try `chmod -R 777` in case you have sub-directories in `public`.

Comment: It finally works! Thanks, I'll award the bounty as soon as I can.

Comment: Wait a second...apparently, redeploying the app reverts this change. Any idea how I can get it to be permanent?

Comment: @JoeMorano How do you deploy the app? Do you use Git or just replace some directory?

Comment: @JoeMorano Maybe you need to do it upper in the directory hierarchy. `chmod -R 777 /rails_apps/website/releases`. And if that alone doesn't solve it, then do `setfacl -Rdm other:rwx /rails_apps/website/releases`.

Comment: @HelderPereira The first command doesn't change the reset behavior, and for the second command, I get back the error "-bash: setfacl: command not found".

Comment: @JoeMorano You can try `/bin/setfacl -Rdm other:rwx /rails_apps/website/releases` just in case there is a problem with your PATH. If you get the same error, you need to install ACL, but you need sudo permissions for that. If you have, do `sudo apt-get install acl` and then try the `setfacl` again.

Comment: If I run 'chmod -R 777' every time I deploy, I can always add pictures...the only problem is that the pictures I added before are deleted. Do you think those two issues are even related? I don't see why the permissions being reset would delete assets...

Comment: @JoeMorano No, they are not related, `chmod` does not delete anything. I think the problem is how you deploy it, as I suppose a new directory is created inside `/rails_apps/website/releases` every time you deploy. Maybe you should create a new question explaining how you deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

It is about your folder and file permissions on your deployment machine and not about rails.

Comment: You mean the machine I use to deploy my app to the internet?

Comment: Right, permissions on this folder or any other folder up restrict writing into it for whatever user you use for deployment.

Comment: Do you know how I can change the permissions?

Comment: You should read about "chmod" command. I probably, should be putting this answer as a comment. I suggest you to google for step-by-step deployment instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add writability to not just to the `..../public` folder but specifically to subfolders under `..../avatars/`. So do this:

```
chmod -R a+w /rails_apps/website/releases/20150807211111/public/system/users/avatars
```

This is generally considered bad practice though. You should rather change owner or group of the folder to that of the user running the web server. Then make sure that this user/group can write to that folder.

Something like:

```
 chown -R www-data:www-data /rails_apps/website/releases/
```

Your needs may vary though.

Using Capistrano for deployment helps to completely automate the needed changes upon code deployment.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem long time ago and the following works for me;

`chmod 755 /rails_apps/website/releases/20150807211111/public`

if you have your own machine:

`chmod 777 /rails_apps/website/releases/20150807211111/public`

Comment: Do you know what the difference is between this answer and the answer that says 'chmod -R +w /rails_apps...'?

Comment: 777  ensures Owner, Group and Users have "rwx" set, AND NOTHING MORE

and 
+w: add write permission
-R:  change files and directories recursively

Comment: I tried both commands, but each time I got back the exact same error.

Comment: you just need to make your all directories available for rwx. The above mentioned is good as `chmod -R 777`